# Maintaining UTM codes when Devise redirects to request password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Regarding a Ruby on Rails 4.2.5 + Devise 3.4.1 app.

Some of the marketing around our app requires UTM codes. Sometimes, the marketing links point to resources that require a login to view. The problem is that when Devise redirects to the login screen, the UTM codes are removed, and Analytics counts the lead as an internal link, rather than crediting the UTM info properly.

Is there any easy way to fix this? And if not, a pointer to the right direction on what needs doing would be great.

Comment: But after login, does it not redirect to the linked page with proper UTM code?

Comment: Nope. The UTM codes are stripped off.

Comment: This might not be possible without monkeypatching devise internals. But desperate times call for desperate measures :) I'll try something when I have a bit of free time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In it's default configuration, Devise shouldn't be stripping out any parameters when redirecting after a successful login. The original URL is stored on auth failure, and then the stored URL is used verbatim as the redirect location after successful login.

So:

```
# /path?utm_campaign=test
# => redirects to /user/login on auth challenge
# => redirects back to /path?utm_campaign=test on login
```

Are you overriding `after_sign_in_path_for` by any chance? If so, it's worth looking at the [original code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.4.1/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L211), and ensure that you are retaining `stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)` - which effects the behaviour described above.

Comment: There was some misbehaving code, sure enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be rendering the login form via ajax on the marketing page and instead of redirecting to the login page, have the login page come to you.

```
def marketing_landing_page
  unless user_signed_signed_in? 
    render :new
 end
end
```

:new as in devise/sessions/new